# Is it possible to apply a Content Security nonce in a js script imported from another js file?

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy

My backend service generates a Content Security Policy as the following:

```
Content-Security-Policy
    default-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self'; form-action 'self'; script-src 'nonce-4VOtk0Uo1l7pwtC';
```

The rendered HTML uses nonce in the script tags to allow its execution:

```
<script nomodule src="https://xxx/build/script1.js" nonce="4VOtk0Uo1l7pwtC"></script>

<script type="module" src="https://xxx/build/script2.js" nonce="4VOtk0Uo1l7pwtC"></script>
```

These script are loaded correctly. The problem is script2.js includes an import statement to load another script:

```
import{p as e,b as t}from"./p-cfa9fa8a.js";
```

This one is blocked by the csp policy, as it doesn't include the nonce parameter:

```
TypeError: error loading dynamically imported module undefined p-cfa9fa8a.js:1:12156

Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”). p-cfa9fa8a.js:1:12156
```

Comment: Have you ever wondered why "*blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“**default-src**”)*", although you have a `script-src` directive? It looks like you have inline styles blocked, not scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add the `'strict-dynamic'` option:

> The strict-dynamic source expression specifies that the trust
> explicitly given to a script present in the markup, by accompanying it
> with a nonce or a hash, shall be propagated to all the scripts loaded
> by that root script. At the same time, any allow-list or source
> expressions such as 'self' or 'unsafe-inline' are ignored. See
> script-src for an example.

```
Content-Security-Policy
    default-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self'; form-action 'self'; script-src 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-4VOtk0Uo1l7pwtC';
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not a solution since Safari browser does not support `'strict-dynamic'`.

Comment: It does now according to https://portswigger.net/daily-swig/safari-adds-strict-csp-support-catches-up-with-other-leading-browsers